# OpenCV. How to identify i-frames only for a video file encoded in MPEG format

Tags: opencv

I need to extract only the i-frames from an MPEG encoded video file(it may be a .avi file or .mp4 file). Is it possible to atleast identify the i-frames.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [this](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/ticket/92) ffmpeg enhancement can accomplish this for you using the select filter to filter all I-Frames. You may need to build ffmpeg from source to get this capability I'm not sure. [Here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1438052) is an Ubuntu guide with the details, and [here](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) is where you can get the nightly Windows binary version.

**EDIT:** OpenCV relies on ffmpeg API's to capture video from a file. However, the functionality you want is a bit specific, so you are going to need to write your own custom filtering module with ffmpeg's libavfilter. [Here](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=FFmpeg_filter_HOWTO) is one of their how to guides on using libavfilter. In particular, as I mentioned above, you will probably want to use the **[select](http://www.ffmpeg.org/libavfilter.html#SEC49)** filter provided by libavfilter. This will filter all I-frames from the stream for you to process.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I am not familiar with Ubuntu, linux. I am good with windows. Streaming video has some specific format in binary terms like header. May be if i know how to read header for each coming frame i can read weather it is I-frame or p-frame or B-frame. I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Parsing a binary stream looking for header information will work for a particular codec, but if you want your code to be maximally flexible, I would recommend leveraging countless man-hours that have gone into creating ffmpeg.