# How to find the frame type(i frame,p frame, b frame)?

Tags: opencv, video-encoding, multimedia

i am working in opencv 2.4.7 , is there any function to determine whether the captured frame is I frame, P frame , B frame?

if not which libs i must use to identify the frames

Answer (score 1):

Caveat - I don't use opencv.

There doesn't seem to be a well-documented library function for it, but would either of these at least suggest a route?

[How to get number of I/P/B frames of a video file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15244758/how-to-get-number-of-i-p-b-frames-of-a-video-file)

[OpenCV. How to identify i-frames only for a video file encoded in MPEG format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775263/opencv-how-to-identify-i-frames-only-for-a-video-file-encoded-in-mpeg-format)